# Why when running the api for google slide batch update I get a 503 Service unavailable response?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-slides-api

The service was working fine, but 48 hours ago this problem started. I have a backend application running, I receive a POST request with a list of slides id´s to remove from a google slides presentation. 48 hrs ago when I request to google slides api to remove the list of slides id´s from presentation I receive a 503  status response "service not available" . What this issue is related with? the application was working fine for more of 2 months

I have tried to create a new GCP project with my current gmail account, also I have created a new gmail account and a new project from there . According to the response message it looks like the issue came from google api but has been a long time and the issue still happening

Comment: You receive http 503 when attempting to use the Google Slides API call? Can you provide the code you are trying which is causing the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your response, sure, You can take a look to the code here https://github.com/cmembreno2/g-slides-app.git

Answer (score 0):

I have quite the same problem, my process was working well for a month or two and since monday it's now bugging on each and every tries with the error 503.

My code is making several API calls and it's almost never bugging on the same slides API call, but eventually the code never comes to an end successfully.

I contacted the Google Cloud dev support and even if they cannot identify the reason or propose a stable solution to my bug, they said they had other similar cases over the last few hours.

A quick fix/dirty solution I found to make it work is to make an error handling to retry each API call if buggy up to 5 times with sleeping time of 60sec between each try.

I'd be interested if any clean solution comes out on this thread.
I'll let you know if I have some news from the Google cloud support.

Siméo

Edit 2023-02-23:
This issue has been solved by the Google Cloud Support, you should not be facing this errors anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for share your experience, let me know if something new comes up or if google cloud dev support find a solution , I will appreciate it , thanks a lot!